# cannot insert any string into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, string, insert

I have a problem with inserting strings into mysql. I can insert numbers but cant strings. Can anybody look at this?  Thanks for your help.

My table(episodes) looks like

```
id  int(11) notnull          
serie   int(11) notnull          
name    varchar(255)    notnull          
comment varchar(255)    notnull          
embed   varchar(255)    notnull
```

And here is the PHP code:

```
<?php
require_once "config.php";

$connect = mysql_connect( "$db_host", "$db_user", "$db_pw") or die(mysql_error());  
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die( mysql_error() );

if(isset($_POST['pridatdiel'])) {   
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `episodes` (`id`, `serie`, `name`, `comment`, `embed`)
    VALUES ('', '$cisloserie', '$menodielu', '$popis', '$embed')");
    header("refresh: 0;");
}

function stripinput($text) {
    if (!is_array($text)) {
        $text = stripslash(trim($text));
        $text = preg_replace("/(&amp;)+(?=\#([0-9]{2,3});)/i", "&", $text);
        $search = array("&", "\"", "'", "\\", '\"', "\'", "<", ">", "&nbsp;");
        $replace = array("&amp;", "&quot;", "&#39;", "&#92;", "&quot;", "&#39;", "&lt;", "&gt;", " ");
        $text = str_replace($search, $replace, $text);
    } else {
        foreach ($text as $key => $value) {
            $text[$key] = stripinput($value);
        }
    }
    return $text;
}

if(isset($_POST['menodielu'])) {$menodielu = stripinput($_POST['menodielu']);}
if(isset($_POST['cisloserie'])) {$cisloserie = stripinput($_POST['cisloserie']);}
if(isset($_POST['popis'])) {$popis = stripinput($_POST['popis']);}
if(isset($_POST['embed'])) {$embed = stripinput($_POST['embed']);}

echo '    
  <form method="post">    
  meno dielu<input type="text" name="menodielu">       
  <select name="cisloserie">'; 
  $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `series`") or die(mysql_error());   
  while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
  {
  echo "<option value=".$info['serie_id'].">".$info['serie_id']."</option>";
  }
  echo '
  </select>     
  popis<input type="text" name="popis">        
  embed<input type="text" name="embed">      
  <input type="submit" value="pridať diel" name="pridatdiel">
  </form>
 ';
?>
```

Comment: You don't check for errors. How do you expect to figure this out if you don't do that? Use `mysql_error()` to get the error MySQL is reporting.

Comment: If you were using prepared statements, you'd be done already.  And you wouldn't have to do all that input mangling first.

Answer (score 0):

You're executing your query:

```
if(isset($_POST['pridatdiel'])) {   
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `episodes` (`id`, `serie`, `name`, `comment`, `embed`)
    VALUES ('', '$cisloserie', '$menodielu', '$popis', '$embed')");
    header("refresh: 0;");
}
```

... before you've initialised the variables:

```
if(isset($_POST['menodielu'])) {$menodielu = stripinput($_POST['menodielu']);}
if(isset($_POST['cisloserie'])) {$cisloserie = stripinput($_POST['cisloserie']);}
if(isset($_POST['popis'])) {$popis = stripinput($_POST['popis']);}
if(isset($_POST['embed'])) {$embed = stripinput($_POST['embed']);}
```

MySQL is seeing a query which has an empty value inserted for every field. You should turn up PHP's error reporting level so that it warns you when you try to use an undefined variable:

```
error_reporting(-1);
```

Please use the PHP-provided `mysql_real_escape_string()` function rather than your `stripinput()`. Going forward you should also avoid using the deprecated `mysql` extension altogether - use `PDO` or `mysqli` both of which support prepared statements.